# json:how to get other values of json response and insert in to the other key

Tags: json

hey guys anyone help me how to get the values from key Request and insert it to the other key or object?

```
"response": {
        "deleted_users": {
            "26": {
                "sfid": ""
            },
            "27": {
                "sfid": ""
            },
            "28": {
                "sfid": ""
            }
        }
    },
    "errors": [],
    "request": [
        "0056F00000B1tkGQAA",
        "0056F00000B1tkGQAB",
        "0056F00000B1tkGQAC"
    ]
```

Comment: Right now, it's not very clear what you're trying to do with this JSON. "Get values from one, and put into another" just isn't very descriptive. Beyond that, what have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? There's plenty of resources about JSON, so it'll help if you narrow things down for us. You can add more information to your question by making an [edit].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply get it by `{!v.values.request}`, you must first have an attribute storing that JSON value. `<aura:attribute name="values" type="Object"/>`

Then you can now call another method and pass the values there using `{!v.values.JSON_CONTENT}`

Please make your question clearer, but based on my understanding, this is how you can simply access the values and pass it to another methods.

Comment: It's not clear that this user is working in Lighting at all.

Comment: Yes, he should make his question clearer.